# Overwrite specific JSON values but keep the ones that aren't overwritten

Tags: react-native, overwrite

I'm currently working on an application where I receive data from server-sent-events. the data stream sends everything once in the beginning and updates only the fields that need to be updated. My question is how I can save both the original JSON object and update only the updated items.

At this moment, all items are updated. For example, if I receive a standard JSON object with 2 items `{color: "black", id: 0}` and I receive the following update `{ id: 1 }`, the object is as follows `{color: "", id: 1}` So the object is overwritten by an empty item because it was not there.

```js
const [initialUserData, setInitialUserData] = useState({
  id: 1,
  name: 'Pol',
  color: 'black',
});

useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe = sse.subscribe('playerupdate', (d: any) => {
    const receivedData = d;
    const updatedUserData = { ...initialUserData, ...receivedData }; // Create a copy of initialUserData

    // Iterate over the keys in receivedData and update updatedUserData
    for (const key in receivedData) {
      if (receivedData.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        updatedUserData[key] = receivedData[key];
        console.log(key);
      }
    }

    updateUserData(updatedUserData);

    if (updatedUserData.PlayerId > 0) {
      setSessionState(true);
    } else if (updatedUserData.PlayerId === 0) {
      setSessionState(false);
    }
  });

  return unsubscribe;
}, []);
```

I am using ReactJs Context API, which is new to me, but it doesn't seem to be an issue since it updates perfectly.

Comment: I think you are suffering because of lack of JavaScript knowledge.

Comment: Then end my suffering and give advice

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed it by making a normal let variable instead of a useState and updating it once. From then on the updatedUserData receives updates and puts both the variables together!

```js
    let initialUserData = {
       id: 1,
      name: 'Pol',
      color: 'black'
    };

    useEffect(() => {
      const unsubscribe = sse.subscribe('playerupdate', (receivedData: any) => {
        if (receivedData.color === "white") {
          initialUserData = receivedData
        }

        const data = { ...initialUserData, ...receivedData };
        updateUserData(data);

        setSessionState(data.PlayerId > 0);
      return unsubscribe;
    }, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at my edition:

```js
const [initialUserData, setInitialUserData] = useState({
  id: 1,
  name: 'Pol',
  color: 'black',
});

useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe = sse.subscribe('playerupdate', (receivedData: any) => {
    // Merge the receivedData into the initialUserData
    const updatedUserData = { ...initialUserData, ...receivedData };

    updateUserData(updatedUserData);

    setSessionState(updatedUserData.PlayerId > 0);
  });

  return unsubscribe;
}, []);
```

You don't need that `for in` loop. And I added another correction in the `setSessionState`. There is no need to add tons of codes when the value is boolean, and you can directly use them instead of using `if-then else`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion and for the question edits! The flow is as follows. The 'initialUserData' acts like a placeholder until the actual data is received. This process works and the actual data shows with your code but as soon as the color item is updated, everything is overwritten by the initialUserData placeholder variable but with the updates. The actual data is gone and is only updated 30s later. Is their a way to save this actual data or will it always go back to the placeholder data?

Comment: @ThomasDierickx, What are you saying bro? The actual data comes from API, okay. Then, by using the setter function of the state, it will be replaced by a merge to the placeholder, which means some keys will be updated. OK, Then why will actual data be gone? and what is this 30 seconds?

Comment: The actual data is gone because it is constantly being overwritten by the initialUserData value

Comment: Is this overwritten your logic? or does it happen unintentionally?

Comment: unintentionally. I receive 1 object when i setup the SSE stream, this object should be stored and from that i only receive updates and those should be reflected on to the originally received object. The items in the object that aren't updated should stay there and not disappear

Comment: I can't understand what you want @ThomasDierickx. Write on a paper what you want and stage them. And then do them step by step. it's my only help. thanks.